# Android - Unit tests not working together?

Tags: android, testing, preferences, shared

I have two unit test that are testing two functions in a shared preferences util. Which ever test occurs second (`testSaveBusinesses()`), does not work.  There's a `NPE` for `UserPreferencesUtil.getBusinesses(context).size()`. However, if I take out the first test, `testSaveBusinesses()` will pass. What gives?

```
public class UserPreferencesUtilTest extends ActivityTestCase {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> industries = null;
private ArrayList<String> businesses = null;

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
    industries = new ArrayList<>();

    industries.add("Airlines & Transportation");
    industries.add("Consumer Products");
    industries.add("Financial Services");

    businesses = new ArrayList<>();
    businesses.add("Strategy");
    businesses.add("Performance Improvement");
}


public void testSaveIndustries() {

    UserPreferencesUtil.saveIndustries(context, industries);
    assertEquals(3, UserPreferencesUtil.getIndustries(context).size());

}

public void testSaveBusinesses() {

    UserPreferencesUtil.saveBusinesses(context, businesses);
    assertEquals(2, UserPreferencesUtil.getBusinesses(context).size());

}
```

EDIT: If I combine these functions, the test will past.

Comment: It's going to be hard to say without seeing the code for either method under test.

Comment: Need more details, but I guest UserPreferencesUtil.getBusinesses(context) return null

Comment: See my edit. Also, that function should be `returning an ArrayList<String>`

Comment: please show NPE stacktrace and UserPreferencesUtil source